# How to create mysql function in rails test database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rails-migrations

I wrote a Mysql function for my rails app and i added it to my database by manual.
 When i want to test the function using Rails UNIT test, it through the errors like below

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: FUNCTION mydatabase.fn_Sample_Function does not exist:
```

How to add the function, out of the test suite or beginning of test run ?

Thanks in Advance,
Aaa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see the error. But I assume the problem is your schema format.

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

in application.rb should be what you need to do.

The reason behind that is by default your test database is not made from a schema only dump of your development database, but, instead from db/schema.rb - which knows nothing about mysql functions.

an sql schema format will do a mysqldump (or pg_dump) with the schema only flag set to true and create a development_structure.sql file.

Comment: Thanks for the Quick answer, i am using 2.3.12 version. I don't think we can use config object in application.rb file.. Please correct me if i was wrong.. i added it in enviroment.rb file but no help..

Comment: ok - environment.rb is fine - did it create the development_structure file?

Comment: environment.rb is the place to add this configuration. Please run `rake db:schema:dump` to generate the schema.rb in the sql format and then run your unit tests.